# Image is not being responsive even with 100% width/max-width

Tags: html, css

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykn2p.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRfJB.png) I am trying to make the Google Search Page in HTML & CSS. However, when I try to center the Google Logo, the image re-adjusts itself when the device width is changed. I've been stuck in this section for quite a while now, and cannot seem to find any answers to my inquiry. Some assistance would be appreciated.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: #202124;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  word-spacing: 11px;
  padding-top: 13px;
  padding-right: 129px;
}

.navbartxt a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.navbartxt a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.dots {
  width: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 123px;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.pfp {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-top: -7px;
  margin-left: 163px;
}

.searchbox {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
}

.searchsections {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.Google {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 72px;
  margin-left: 240px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbartxt">
      <a href="#">Gmail</a>
      <a href="#">Images</a>
    </div>

    <img class="dots" src="/CSS/CSS Images/9 dots.png" />

    <img class="pfp" src="/CSS/CSS Images/MyPfpGoogle.png" />
  </div>
</nav>

<section class="searchsections">
  <div class="Google">
    <img src="/CSS/CSS Images/Google Logo.png" />
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: could you upload the images you are using, by posting them to this post

Comment: Ok ok. I am a beginner so mistakes are expected to be made—no need to have a go at me for my wrongdoing...

Comment: Added the images.

Comment: take it not at going at you but as a hint to overthink certain mechanics and as ahint where your code fails and where you need to get back to to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your `.Google` class with this :-

```
.Google {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* for horizontal center */
  align-items: center; /* For Vertical Center */
}

.Google > img {
  display: block;
}
```

How it works learn [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp)